# Understanding spies in Typescript using Jasmine

Tags: jasmine2.0

I am trying to understand how to use Spies in Typescript using Jasmine. I have found [this documentation and this example](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html):

```
describe("A spy", function() {
  var foo, bar = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      setBar: function(value) {
        bar = value;
      }
    };

    spyOn(foo, 'setBar').and.callThrough();
  });

  it("can call through and then stub in the same spec", function() {
    foo.setBar(123);
    expect(bar).toEqual(123);

    foo.setBar.and.stub();
    bar = null;

    foo.setBar(123);
    expect(bar).toBe(null);
  });
});
```

In order to use Spies I have created a method:

```
export class HelloClass {
    hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and I am trying to Spy it:

```
import { HelloClass } from '../src/helloClass';

describe("hc", function () {
  var hc = new HelloClass();

  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(hc, "hello").and.throwError("quux");
  });

  it("throws the value", function() {
    expect(function() {
      hc.hello
    }).toThrowError("quux");
  });
});
```

but it results in:

```
[17:37:31] Starting 'compile'...
[17:37:31] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 2.0.6
[17:37:33] Finished 'compile' after 1.9 s
[17:37:33] Starting 'test'...
F.......
Failures: 
1) Calculator throws the value
1.1) Expected function to throw an Error.

8 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 0 seconds
[17:37:33] 'test' errored after 29 ms
[17:37:33] Error in plugin 'gulp-jasmine'
Message:
    Tests failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never actually invoking `hc.hello` and hence it is never throwing.

Try this as your test:

```
it("throws the value", function() {
  expect(hc.hello).toThrowError("quux");
});
```

What's going on here is that `expect(...).toThrowError` is expecting a function that, when invoked, will throw an error. I'm sure you knew this, but just got caught up in the fact that you left off parens in the function.